# Using AutoMapper, is it possible to map a property value to a property?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper for C# and I'm trying to convert a property value into a property name.

Consider the following:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string ParamA { get; set; }
    public string ParamB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of ClassB instances and I'm trying to convert the value of "Val" property from ClassB into the correct property of ClassA based on the value of "Name":

```
ClassB b1 = new ClassB() {Name = "ParamA", Val = "ValueA"};
ClassB b2 = new ClassB() {Name = "ParamB", Val = "ValueB"};
ClassB b3 = new ClassB() {Name = "ParamC", Val = "ValueC"};
List<ClassB> listB = new List<ClassB>() {b1, b2, b3};
```

So using listB I'm trying to create an object of type `ClassA` with `ParamA = "ValueA"` and `ParamB = "ValueB"`, is it possible using AutoMapper or any other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible using AutoMapper or any other tool?

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to do something like this:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();

foreach (var b in listB)
{
    typeof(ClassA)
        .GetProperty(b.Name) //Get property of ClassA of which name is b.Name
        .SetValue(a , b.Val); //Set the value of such property on object a
}
```

Please note that based on your question, `ClassA` should have a property named `ParamC`.

Answer (score 1):

I have once found this piece of code [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp/24919811#24919811) and I am using it ever sinc e for these kinds of things. You put this extension method into your class:

```
    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
      get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null); }
      set { this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null); }
    }
```

and then you can use [] to do

```
ClassA a;
ClassB b;
...
a[b.Name] = b.Val;
```

Comment: I didn't mention that ClassA is 3rd party so I can't add an indexer to it. You're probably correct though, the best way is using Reflection. Thanks!